# Why “left me of” in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

“The reviewers said it was the work of a craftsman: that was all that was left me of what had been a passion.”
I’m a little confused by the “left me of” structure in the second sentence. Could anyone help clarify? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The grouping "left me of" is not what you should consider.  Instead consider "left me" as Hellion did, and separately consider "of"...

> Of what had been a passion, all that was left me was that.

Comment: You are right, I didn’t separately consider “of”, how stupid, that’s why I got confused in the first place. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here, the "me" is an indirect object, as in "he left me a $1 tip" -> "he left a $1 tip for me."  So, something had been a passion for someone, and they presumably created a lot of items as a result of the passion, but this particular "work of a craftsman" is the only thing that was left for "me".

Answer (score -1):

The reviewers said it was the work of a craftsman: that was all that was left me of what had been a passion.

the context and meaning are clear to me but i agree that this sounds very wrong. it seems to be a different way of expessing ...that was all that i had left from what had been a / (my former) passion